# Can we call a parameterized constructor from a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

For example I have class like this

```
public class ABC
{
  private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
  private readonly IConfiguration _config;
  private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

  public ABC(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IConfiguration config, IDistributedCache distributedCache)
  {
   _cache = memoryCache;
   _config = config;
   _distributedCache = distributedCache;
  }
  public ABC() : this(IMemoryCache , IConfiguration ,IDistributedCache )
  {
  }
}
```

As you can see that I have tried to call a Parameterized constructor from a Parameter-less constructor, but that's not possible. Is there any other way to achieve this concept?

Comment: if you are having issues with providing all constructor parameters every time you need an ABC instance, you might want to read about Dependency Injection concept to use it in your application.

Comment: You shouldn't pass Types, but specific instances

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, How can i pass specific instances?
to pass instances, I have to instantiate those instances like this.

public ABC(IConfiguration configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache, IDistributedCache distributedCache) : this(memoryCache, configuration, distributedCache)
        {
        }

Comment: @HasnainLatif `this(blabla)` is like calling a method: `MyMethod(1, "myString")`. You would not call the method with Types like this `MyMethod(Int32, String)`. you would call it with actual values.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in [concrete implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100410/what-is-concrete-implementation/3100452#3100452) of those interfaces, It's just like calling a method. There is nothing *magical* about `this()` syntax apart from where it appears. For example if you have a default implementation of `IMemoryCache` implemented in class `DefaultMemoryCache` you can just 'new that up' and pass it in:

```
public ABC() : this(new DefaultMemoryCache(), etc.)
{
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a static [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) if constructing these dependencies is a bit too complicated:

```
public static ABC CreateNew()
{
    var others = ...
    var cache = new DefaultCache(others, etc.)
    ...
    return new ABC(cache, etc.);
}
```

But if you want to be able to use the interface as your input, this is what you can do: **(Now, this is just an example to make a point, I do not recommend doing this since it would be very confusing and fragile)**

```
    public ABC() : this
    (
        (IMemoryCache) Activator.CreateInstance
        (
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First
            (
                t => typeof(IMemoryCache).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface
            )
        )
    )
    {
    }
```

The [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) code snippet above, in essence, what a [dependency injection](https://codeaddiction.net/articles/10/dependency-injection-in-c---a-simple-introduction) [library](https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2019/01/24/the-ultimate-list-of-net-dependency-injection-frameworks/) would do, and you might want to consider using one if your project is suitable for it.

One last thing, just to have a complete answer, of course, you can also implement a body in your [overloaded contractors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-constructor-overloading/):

```
public class ABC
{
    private readonly ICache _cache;

    public ABC()
    {
        _cache = new Cache();
    }

    public ABC(ICache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
}
```

`: this()` syntax is only required if you want to call other constructors in the same class for code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

use instances not types. create an instance of what ever class fulfills your Interface.

```
public class ABC
{
  private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
  private readonly IConfiguration _config;
  private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

  public ABC(IMemoryCache memoryCache, IConfiguration config, IDistributedCache distributedCache)
  {
   _cache = memoryCache;
   _config = config;
   _distributedCache = distributedCache;
  }
  public ABC() : this(new MemoryCache(), new Configuration(), new DistributedCache() )
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot about braces in constructors